# retrieve value from python shell beginner question

Tags: python, operating-system, stdout, stdin

I can use this [python file](https://github.com/JoelBender/bacpypes/blob/master/samples/ReadProperty.py) from a library to make a read request of a temperature sensor  value via BACnet protocol by running this command from terminal:

`echo 'read 12345:2 analogInput:2 presentValue' | py -3.9 ReadProperty.py`

And I can see in the console the value of `67.02999114990234` is returned as expected.

I apologize if this question seems real silly and entry level, but could I ever call this script and assign a value to the sensor reading? Any tips greatly appreciated.

for example if I run this:

```
import subprocess
read = "echo 'read 12345:2 analogInput:2 presentValue' | python ReadProperty.py"

sensor_reading = subprocess.check_output(read, shell=True)

print("sensor reading is: ",sensor_reading)
```

It will just print `0` but hoping to figure out a way to print the sensor reading of `67.02999114990234`. I think what is happening under the hood is the BACnet library brings up some sort of shell scripting that is using std in/out/flush.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system` does not return the output from stdout, but the exit code of the executed program/code.

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20system#os.system) for more information:

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in the format specified for wait().
> On Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell after running command.

For getting the output from stdout into your program, you have to use the `subsystem` module. There are plenty of tutorials outside on how to use `subsystem`, but this is an easy way:

```py
import subprocess

read = "echo 'read 12345:2 analogInput:2 presentValue' | py -3.9 ReadProperty.py"
sensor_reading = subprocess.check_output(read, shell=True)
print(sensor_reading)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, am learning a bit about this process. So I tested this on Ubuntu (changed my testing script to include `print("sensor reading is: ",sensor_reading)` which ultimately prints `sensor reading is:  b'66.12999725341797\n'`. Would I just need to format this from I think a string into a float? Much appreciation here....

Comment: Well this works, ha. `print("sensor reading is: ",float(sensor_reading))`